# Paypal donate button ionic

Tags: paypal, ionic-framework

i have been strugling a bit with getting this to work, as i prefer not to use the PayPal plugin since it look like much work for the simple thing im trying to achieve.

I have basically followed the PayPal guide to create a donate button which works in a browser, but when i click it inside a ionic project it wont work and i cant get it to open.

I have tried with just the form (which doesnt open the browser with the callback):

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_system"> [...] </form>
```

After that i tried to first open a window and then do the post in that window, but that just closed the window at once.

```
$scope.donate = function() {
    var win = window.open( "about:blank", "_blank" );
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
}
```

I dont really know what can be done from here so any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
On a sidenote, is it possible to use https://www.paypal.com/no/webapps/mpp/send-money-online and then add for example a default receiver email like sendt@me.com somehow?

Comment: Do you get any errors? It could be related to the fact that you may have to whitelist PayPal as described [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

Comment: @Dexter I get no errors and nothing happens at all, it might be that it have to be whitelisted, but linking to for example google play works and opens with no issues. I'll have a look and the whitelist and comment if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem and I solved it, with "ngNoForm". ngNoForm turn off ngSubmit behavior (which prevent default submit on form).

So the code is:

```
<form ngNoForm action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_system"> [...] </form>
```

Comment: Used your code and it worked like a charm. But another issue cropped, after the donation is completed, how does one get redirected to our Ionic Page?

Comment: Maybe this works for redirection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298390/go-back-to-ionic-application-after-payment-success-from-paypal