# Go back to Ionic application after payment success from Paypal

Tags: ionic-framework, paypal

I have created an Ionic app. I have some items to order. Payment is done using Paypal. I have called a web url using window.open(url) which is redirecting me to the Paypal.

I'm able to do the payment successfully, but Can anyone please let me know how I can come back to my ionic app after successful payment.

**Note:** I have not used Paypal plugin as it is not developed for windows

Comment: mm i think it's difficult ..you have to use the inAppBrowser ... open there the page .. then listen for an event and close it

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi I have updated the question, I'm opening it using window.open(url,'_self') 
But how I can listen the event that the payment is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loadsart event of the InAppBrowser to catch the urls when load pages after payment was done. Then you can process your tasks according to those urls and their parameters as you prefer. As an example,  when you have the payment successful url you can navigate back to your app after closing the open browser. Also you can have the data passing back when the payment is success or fail, into your application using this way. Hope this will help to you.

`addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { var currentUrl = event.url /*do the rest according to the url inside your application */});`

I just add a pseudo-code below.

```js
browserRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

  var param = getParameters(event.url); //Read the parameters from the url


  if (isCorrectParameters(param)) { //Check parameters agaist the payment gateway response url
    browserRef.close(); // colse the browser

    //Handle the success and failed scenarios
    if(success){
      $state.go('test');
    }else{
      // handle fail scenario
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I got the event when the payment is successful, after that I wrote `$state.go('test');` but it is not navigating to that state.

Comment: $state.go('test') should work if you got the write url to handle the payment successful event. I just try with my application with $state.go('myPath'). It worked perfectly. But in my real case I just opening a ionic model with successful or failed message.

Comment: Thank you so much... I forgot to add `browserRef.close(); // close the browser`

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: I am using the above code snippet, but is there anyway i can get more information on the Parameters and other Items i will get for success or failure condition? That would be real helpful, as debugging the App on Device is such Pain.

Comment: Only way i found was, passing parameters as query-string and then read the parameters from url (`event.url`) and handle success and fail scenarios

Comment: But when i see the Parameters, there i am getting parameters with keys as `cmd:"_express-checkout-mobile"`  
`token:"EC-<Value>"`  
`useraction:"commit"`

Comment: How do we know what is a success and failure case?

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to achieve this with ionic 5?

Answer (score 2):

Few days back even i was facing the same issue, i was able to do payment where the ionic app drags to the third party api but after the payment it was not redirecting to the ionic app in the mobile/smartphone.
after soing dome R and D i got the solution that when the app is running on the mobile it will not be having any port number running on i,e., http://localhost/dashboard instead of http:localhost:8100/dashboard, where 8100 is the port number running for the ionic server.

after specifying the return back url as **http://localhost/dashboard** i was able to redirect back to the ionic app.

Comment: But how do you do on live mode? Since paypal does not support http in live. Only https is supported as return or cancel url. I'm facing the same issue and nothing helps